# Tensorflow cannot convert string to number

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow-1.12 and when I load data from csv via `tf.data.Dataset`, I cannot convert cell values from strings into numbers. My csv looks like:

```
"string_col1","col1","col2", ...
"some value","23.502482","53.5", ...
```

I want to use only columns with numbers (col1, col2, etc.) as an input, so I have function which drops first column:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def slice_and_transform_to_float(line):
    line_splitted = tf.string_split([line], ",")
    str_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(line_splitted.values, dtype=tf.string)
    str_data = tf.slice(str_data, [1], [col_size])
    return tf.string_to_number(str_data, out_type=tf.float32) # here is a problem


map_func = lambda line: slice_and_transform_to_float(line)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
dataset = dataset.map(map_func, num_parallel_calls=4)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess = tf.Session()
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), iterator.initializer])
next_iter = iterator.get_next()
next_rows = sess.run(next_iter) # here we have exception
```

When I try to run it I've got error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: "23.502482"
     [[{{node StringToNumber}} = StringToNumber[out_type=DT_FLOAT](Slice)]]
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at script.py:100)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,8]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]
```

It seems I have string value which is a number, but tensorflow has a problem with convertion into float. I tried integer values and `tf.float64`, but nothing changed. Do you have any idea what can be possible wrong?

I tried to find similar questions, but I only found problems, when someone wanted to convert "string" into number, which is not my case.

Comment: You are trying to convert to float the string `"23.502482"`, including the quotes, not `23.502482`, that's why it fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing the number strings with the surrounding quotes, which cannot be parsed as numbers. You can remove the quotes for example like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def slice_and_transform_to_float(line):
    line_splitted = tf.strings.split([line], ",")
    str_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(line_splitted.values, dtype=tf.string)
    str_data = tf.slice(str_data, [1], [2])  # Fixed that to 2 for the example
    str_len = tf.strings.length(str_data)
    str_unquoted = tf.strings.substr(str_data, tf.ones_like(str_len), str_len - 2)
    return tf.strings.to_number(str_unquoted, out_type=tf.float32)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(slice_and_transform_to_float('"some value","23.502482","53.5"')))
    # [23.502481 53.5     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes csv file can have rows with or without quotation marks, for example:

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", ...
23.582, "53.5",  12   , ...
```

I've changed Your solution by this:

```py
def slice_and_transform_to_float(line):
    line_splitted = tf.string_split([line], ",")
    str_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(line_splitted.values, dtype=tf.string)
    str_data = tf.slice(str_data, [0], [2]) # Fixed that to 2 for the example
    str_data = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.regex_replace(x, '"', ""), str_data)
    return tf.string_to_number(str_data, out_type=out_type)
```

Now it does not matter whether value contains quotation mark or not.

Comment: In tensorflow 2.0, getting error, module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'string_to_number'

Comment: Code is for tf 1.x. Based on [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/to_number), could You try: 

`tf.strings.to_number(input, out_type=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)`

?